# Placement of observeOn gives me different behavior

Tags: rx-java2

When I run the following snippet I don't see the backpressure.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

    MyFileProcessor pro = new MyFileProcessor();
    Timer t = new Timer();
    t.start();
    Disposable x = pro
            .generateFlowable(
                    new File("path\\to\\file.raw"))
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io(), false).observeOn(Schedulers.io()).map(y -> {
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " xxx");

                return y;
            })

            .subscribe(onNext -> {
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " " + new String(onNext));
                Thread.sleep(100);
            }, Throwable::printStackTrace, () -> {
                System.out.println("Done");
                t.end();
                System.out.println(t.getTotalTime());
            });

    Thread.sleep(1000000000);

}
```

When I run the class above I get an alternating lines of

RxCachedThreadScheduler-1 xxx
RxCachedThreadScheduler-1 Line1
....

Its using the same thread.

Now when I move the observeOn to just before the subscribe, I see a bunch of 
RxCachedThreadScheduler-1 xxx
Followed by a bunch of 
RxCachedThreadScheduler-1 Line1

I am assuming this is back pressure but still the thread used is the same.

Why am I seeing this behavior?
Why is only one thread being utilized?
There is no operator as such for the observeOn to operate on, so why am I seeing this behavior?

[edit]

```java
public Flowable<byte[]> generateFlowable(File file) {
    return Flowable.generate(() -> new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file)), (bufferedIs, output) -> {
        try {
            byte[] data = getMessageRawData(bufferedIs);
            if (data != null)
                output.onNext(data);
            else
                output.onComplete();

        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            output.onError(e);
        }
        return bufferedIs;
    }, bufferedIs -> {
        try {
            bufferedIs.close();
        }
        catch (IOException ex) {
            RxJavaPlugins.onError(ex);
        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is only one thread being utilized?

Works correctly because you check the running thread **after** `observeOn` and thus you are supposed to see the same thread there and below, no matter what happens above it. `subscribeOn` affects `generateFlowable` where, I suppose, you don't print the current thread and thus you don't see it runs on a different IO thread.

> Now when I move the observeOn to just before the subscribe

There shouldn't be any difference unless something odd happens in `generateFlowable`.

Comment: I updated the question with the generate method.
When  print the thread name inside the generateFlow method I see a different thread.  For whatever reason (lack of understanding) I was expecting the threadname to be different inside the subscribe method. The subscribe method executes on the observeon scheduler, makes sense.
Thank you again.

Comment: The printouts of `xxx` and `Line` should come one after the other, so not like bunch of `xxx` followed by bunch of `Line`s. That would only happen if there was a thread switch between `map` and `subscribe`. `blockingSubscribe` can have this effect though as it runs on the main thread that can get late.

Comment: Yes, I finally get it. Part of my confusion was with treating the subscribe method as being treated by the subscribeOn executor, but thats not the case. The observeOn when placed before the subscribe just gives it a different thread, causing the grouping and the thread switching. Thank you.